# How to right-align a column of numbers?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have the following python code :

```
#This program converts the speeds 60 KPH
#through 130 KPH (in 10 kph increments)
#to MPH

#Global constants
START = 60
END = 131
INCREMENT = 10
CONVERSION_FACTOR = 0.6214

def main():
    #Print the table headings
    print('KPH\t\tMPH')
    print('----------------')

    #Print the speeds
    for kph in range(START, END, INCREMENT):
        mph = kph * CONVERSION_FACTOR
        print(kph, '\t\t', format(mph, '.1f'))

#Call the main function
main()
```

Running this code I get the following result :

```
KPH     MPH
----------------
60       37.3
70       43.5
80       49.7
90       55.9
100          62.1
110          68.4
120          74.6
130          80.8
```

How can I right align the second column, so that my results are shown more properly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use `printf` style formating to specify width too.

```
>>> print('%10.2f' % 1.23456)
      1.12
```

In your example you could use:

```
print('%-10i%.1f' % (kph, mph))
```

Comment: Thanks for the example but I still don't get the right alignment, even with your last example.

Answer (score 12):

Use the [Format Specification Mini-Language](http://docs.python.org/library/string.html#formatspec)

```
"{:>10.3}".format(12.34)
```

Result (using `_` for spaces ):

```
______12.3
```